# Converting XML to Array eats a lot of memory

Tags: php, xml, arrays, memory

I am converting 80 MB XML file into an Array() and during process it takes almost 1 GB of RAM. Is it normal? I mean I try to be resource efficient and use xml_parser which reads file line by line, but 1 GB is really surprise for me.

Here is the code:

```
class XmlToArray
{
    protected $_stack = array();
    protected $_file = "";
    protected $_parser = null;

    protected $_root = array();

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->_file = $file;

        $this->_parser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8");
        xml_set_object($this->_parser, $this);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->_parser, "startTag", "endTag");
    }

    public function startTag($parser, $name, $attribs)
    {
        $new_node = array('name' => strtolower($name), 'attr' => $attribs, 'sub' => array());

        $stack = $this->_stack;
        $current = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];

        if (is_array($current))
        {
            $current['s'][] = &$new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_root = &$new_node;
        }

        $this->_stack[] = &$new_node;
    }

    public function endTag($parser, $name)
    {
        array_pop($this->_stack);
    }

    public function convert()
    {
        $fh = fopen($this->_file, "r");
        if (!$fh)
        {
            throw new Exception("fail");
        }

        while (!feof($fh))
        {
            $data = fread($fh, 4096);
            xml_parse($this->_parser, $data, feof($fh));
        }

        return $this->_root;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we tell if your code is doing something to eat up a lot of memory if you don't show us the code?

Comment: Sadly, this is not uncommon. Has to do with the structure of the XML. Arrays with lots of complex details can end up pretty beefy. 10X the size of the file isn't that abnormal. Do you really need to load it all up in one shot?

Comment: @DampeS8N: I do. I however am thinking about caching parts of array to file and then loading it on demand, thanks for Idea. By the way. you should have put your comment as answer, not comment :-)

Comment: I can do that. I thought it was too short for one. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not uncommon. Has to do with the structure of the XML. Arrays with lots of complex details can end up pretty beefy. 10X the size of the file isn't that abnormal. Do you really need to load it all up in one shot?

(OP said I should post this as the answer)